# Calling 3rd Party Module python functions from ironpython in C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, python-textfsm

I have to call textfsm python module functions from c#.
I am using Ironpython for this.

Current code

```
        ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
        string dir2 = @"C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages";
        paths.Add(dir2); // change this path according to your IronPython installation
        engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        var eng = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-package\textfsm.py", scope);
```

I am not getting how to execute the textfsm code after this.How to pass a template and get the output.